# Rotate image on hover div

Tags: html, css, hover

Im trying to make sure that when I hover the parent `<div>`, the `<img>` inside the div should rotate 360 degrees (Hovering the text for example, or space in-between should rotate the image as well)

This is my JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FmLbd/

I think its probably something real simple, however I can't seem to figure out what to change in order to make this "simple" effect work.

Comment: To make the link work, just put `http://` in front of it.

Comment: You can't post a jsfiddle link without posting some code here

Comment: I know, i tried but I keep getting the same error over and over.

Comment: btw do u need 360 .. it will be the same image

Comment: Your code seems fine to me, you are rotating `.rotate` when it's being hovered and you gave the rotate to `img`.

Comment: "div > img:hover" instead of ".rotate:hover" . This will rotate all the immediate img under a div which is a parent  http://jsfiddle.net/FmLbd/1/

Comment: Thats correct, but when I add the "rotate" class to the parent div it rotates the entire div. I just need the image to rotate when hovering the div.

Comment: @user3231901 is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/FmLbd/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change your css to:

```
div:hover .rotate {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

Instead of:

```
.rotate {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

Hope this helps!

[**JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/FmLbd/5/)

Answer (score 2):

you should use nested selectors...

```
.onethirdcolumn:hover .rotate {/*add css effects here*/}
```

This CSS matches any elements with the class 'rotate' that are a child of an element with 'onethirdcolumn' when it is hovered. So in effect, styles the 'rotate' class when it's parent 'onethirdcolumn' class is hovered.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**1st Method:** When div is hovered all its immediate `<img />` child tag rotates.

```
div:hover > img {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

**2nd method:** Rotates the immediate child `<img />` with class `.rotate` *(more specificity)*

```
    div:hover > img.rotate {
      -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
      -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
      -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
      transform:rotate(360deg);
   }
```

**3rd method:** Rotates when parent div is hovered. All sub child `<img />` tag with classname `.rotate` will rotate *(Less specific compared to 2nd)*

```
 div:hover img.rotate {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transform:rotate(360deg);
 }
```

When you hover a parent div your immediate `<img />` child will rotate to 360 degree

**Fiddle** - [check here](http://jsfiddle.net/FmLbd/4/)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, like JQuery, but for CSS just change your CSS to

```
div:hover .rotate {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```